# In R: Is there a comparable function to Unix's "find"?

Tags: r, unix

I want a version of this in R.

```
find . ( -type d -name "example_folder_*" ) -prune -print > directory.csv
```

The reason:

I am receiving a directory that contains a large amount of files and subdirectories.  I want to know where all folders that have this format, "example_folder_", are located.

Comment: see `?system`, `?system2`, `?pipe` etc

Answer (score 1):

R has a function called `list.dirs(arg)` that will return a vector of a directories under and including arg.  I don't think there is an equivalent of -prune.  Once you have the directory tree vector though, it should be easy to filter with the standard R tools.

Comment: True, I can use that and set recursive = TRUE but that will go through everything.  I want to stop once I hit the pattern I'm searching for.  The difference will result in thousands of files I won't needlessly be searching through

Comment: I doubt this exists directly, but you can run the exact find command with system(intern=TRUE)